# Laravel auth not working using correct username/password combination

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

For some reason, I'm unable to login with the correct username/password combination. I'm using flash messages to show when the login information is incorrect.

I've tried creating multiple accounts to make sure I wasn't actually entering the wrong login credentials, but after about an hour of fiddling it's still not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Here's what I got.

**UsersController.php (postCreate)** - Function that creates my user account (working perfectly fine)

```
public function postCreate() {

        $rules = array(
        'username'=>'required|unique:users,username|alpha_dash|min:4',
        'password'=>'required|min:8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'=>'required|min:8',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email'
        );

        $input = Input::only(
            'username',
            'password',
            'password_confirmation',
            'email'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        //$confirmation_code = str_random(30);

        User::create(array(
            'username'=>Input::get('username'),
            'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
            'email'=>Input::get('email')
            //'comfirmation_code' => $confirmation_code
        ));

        // Mail::send('email.verify', function($message) {
        //  $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('username'))
        //      ->subject('Verify your email address');
        // });

        // Flash::message('Thanks for signing up! Please check your email.');

        return Redirect::to('login')->with('message', 'Thanks for signing up! Please check your email.');
    }
```

**UsersController.php (postLogin)** - Function that logs me into account

```
public function postLogin() {
        $user = array(
            'email'=>Input::get('email'),
            'password'=>Input::get('password')
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($user)){
            return Redirect::intended('account')->with('message', 'Welcome back!');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->with('message', 'Your username/password was incorrect')
                ->withInput();

        }
    }
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('login', array('as'=>'login', 'uses'=>'UsersController@getLogin'));
Route::post('login', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UsersController@postLogin'));
```

**login.blade.php - My login Page**

```
@if($errors->has())
        <p>The following errors have occured:</p>

        <ul id="form-errors">
            {{ $errors->first('username', '<li>:message</li>') }}
            {{ $errors->first('password', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        </ul>   
    @endif

    @if (Session::has('message'))
        <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
    @endif

    {{ Form::open(array('action'=>'login')) }}

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}<br />
        {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username')) }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}<br />
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::submit('Login') }}
    </p>

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your

**UsersController.php (postCreate) -** : You are able to create using  `password` with **Hash**  `'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password')),`

AND

**UsersController.php (postLogin)**  : You are trying to login using  `'password'=>Input::get('password')`   So this should replace with

**`'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password'))`**

Also hashed passwords required 64 charactters for database field. so check that too.

Comment: After further inspection I found that hashing the password when logging in is not the correct thing to do. I had assumed that it worked because it redirected successfully, but this was not the case. The reason it wasn't working is because I had the password field set to varchar(32) and hashed passwords required 64. You should update to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be with the amount of characters I was allowing to be entered into the password field of the database.

I had the password column set to: `$table->string('password', 32);` varchar(32) which wont work because hashed passwords in laravel require at least 64 characters.

**Changing the password column in my database to varchar(64) fixed the issue.**

Comment: Interestingly enough, this did not work for me. I was using 24, but no change after switching to 64.